# ASP.NET MVC: “An internal error occurred.” when loading certificate bytes with X509Certificate2

Tags: exception, asp.net-mvc-3, x509certificate2

I have already spent a few hours to resolve this error. The weird thing is when I use [this](https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp) libraries independently, it works absolutely fine but when I integrate them with my ASP .NET MVC website, it start throwing the following exception. I have also used MachineKeySet flag based on suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345262/an-internal-error-occurred-when-loading-pfx-file-with-x509certificate2) but still no luck. Could anyone please help me to get rid of this exception. Thanks.

> An internal error occurred.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:
>   An internal error occurred.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 194:            if
>   (string.IsNullOrEmpty(p12FilePassword))
>    Line 196: certificate = new X509Certificate2(p12FileBytes, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
>   Line 197:            else

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/issues/detail?id=47). Looks like a known issue. I used `X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable` flags together and problem disappeared. Other solution is to change the identity of applicationpool to LOCALSERVICE.